# "java.io.IOException: Stream closed" with new BufferedReader

Tags: java, stream, bufferedreader, ioexception

Many people asked question like that but this one is a little bit different. Here is the code:

```
public static BufferedReader reader;    
public static String readString() throws IOException {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String s = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();
            return s;
        }
```

While program runtime `readString` method is invoked many times. The second call causes `exception: stream closed`. I can not understand: why it ends up so? Every time we declare new `BufferedReader`. So the `stream` must be also new. Or not?

If not, how should I organize my program so that it will close reader after all invocations and after my program is over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `System.in` is same `Object` (*`public final static InputStream in;`* of `System` class) both method *calls* are using, closing in one method will automatically close `System.in` for other method. You should close the `BufferedReader` from *outside*(*as I can see it's `public`*) the method once you finish calling `readString` and so it will ultimately close underlying `System.in`.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the `BufferedReader` closes `System.in`. You shouldn't close it at all, and you shouldn't keep creating a new one either: you will lose data. Use the same one for the life of the process.